# Styling Boxes in ie9 - CSS Cross Browser Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Im having some trouble with a website in ie9.

The boxes should stack into individual projects like the below screenshots but in ie9 the bottom intro text area creates a separate box for itself and goes out of line...

It should look like this:
http://pagedev.co.uk/qube-issue/2.png
But its like this:
http://pagedev.co.uk/qube-issue/1.png

My html is:

```
<div class="projects-wrapper">
    <!--Open Brief Project-->
    <div class="projects-single">
        <a href="#"><img src="<?php the_field( 'thumbnail' ); ?>"></a>
        <div class="project-intro">
            <h3><?php the_field( 'project_title' ); ?><h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Close Brief Project-->
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.projects-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:45px;
}

.projects-single {
    width:30%;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin-right:3%;
    margin-bottom:35px;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:left;
}

.projects-single img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
}

.project-intro  {
    width:83%;
    height:auto;
    padding-left:8%;
    padding-right:8%;
    padding-top:6%;
    padding-bottom:6%;
}

.project-intro h3   {
    margin-bottom:0px;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

I am struggling to figure out what i need to change to get it working in ie9

If you need anymore info let me know and ill post it up.

Any help would be great!

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your markup, your `h3` element is not closed.

Corrected:

```
<h3><?php the_field( 'project_title' ); ?></h3>
```

Comment: Something so simple! HA Thank you :)